# C++ file formatting and output to a file

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a piece of code that prints something,like this,

```
u_int packetCount = 0;
    while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, &data) >= 0)
    {

        // Show the packet number
        printf("Packet # %i\n", ++packetCount);

        // Show the size in bytes of the packet
        printf("Packet size: %d bytes\n", header->len);

        // Show a warning if the length captured is different
        if (header->len != header->caplen)
            printf("Warning! Capture size different than packet size: %ld bytes\n", header->len);

        // Show Epoch Time
        printf("Epoch Time: %d:%d seconds\n", header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec);

        // loop through the packet and print it as hexidecimal representations of octets
        // We also have a function that does this similarly below: PrintData()
        for (u_int i=0; (i < header->caplen ) ; i++)
        {
            // Start printing on the next after every 16 octets
            if ( (i % 16) == 0) printf("\n");

            // Print each octet as hex (x), make sure there is always two characters (.2).
            printf("%.2x ", data[i]);

        }

        // Add two lines between packets
        printf("\n\n");
    }
```

The last line gives me output like

```
Packet # 39
Packet size: 54 bytes
Epoch Time: 1084443432:328438 seconds

fe ff 20 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 45 00 
00 28 0f 5c 40 00 80 06 91 d8 91 fe a0 ed 41 d0 
e4 df 0d 2c 00 50 38 af ff f3 11 4c a9 48 50 10 
24 14 31 71 00 00 

Packet # 40
Packet size: 54 bytes
Epoch Time: 1084443445:216971 seconds

00 00 01 00 00 00 fe ff 20 00 01 00 08 00 45 00 
00 28 c0 ad 40 00 2f 06 31 87 41 d0 e4 df 91 fe 
a0 ed 00 50 0d 2c 11 4c a9 48 38 af ff f3 50 11 
19 20 3c 64 00 00 

Packet # 41
Packet size: 54 bytes
Epoch Time: 1084443445:216971 seconds

fe ff 20 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 45 00 
00 28 0f 5f 40 00 80 06 91 d5 91 fe a0 ed 41 d0 
e4 df 0d 2c 00 50 38 af ff f3 11 4c a9 49 50 10 
24 14 31 70 00 00 

Packet # 42
Packet size: 54 bytes
Epoch Time: 1084443457:374452 seconds

fe ff 20 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 45 00 
00 28 0f 62 40 00 80 06 91 d2 91 fe a0 ed 41 d0 
e4 df 0d 2c 00 50 38 af ff f3 11 4c a9 49 50 11 
24 14 31 6f 00 00
```

I need to print the output of this line "`printf("%.2x ", data[i]);`
" and then write this output into a file in C++. Can I please know how to do it?

Comment: Is your question *"How to write hexadecimal numbers to a file?"* ? Or what do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `fstream` standard library. An example of writing to a file can be found at [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/is_open/).

Comment: Hey,I looked at it. But I need to write to the file with the formatting of "%.2". How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: You can use IO manipulators like setprecision and hex from the iomanip library. These will allow you to format anything you stream to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::setw` and `std::hex` to control width and how numbers are printed. `std::dec` will take you back to decimal (base 10) format. Use `std::setfill('0')` to fill with zero.

[I should point out that in all known implementations, `fstream` will call `printf` [or more likely `snprintf` or some similar function] internally, so it's not much gain, other than "it looks like C++" to use `fstream` over `fprintf`]

Comment: Do you mean   fprintf(pFile,"std::hex",data[i]); if pFile in my text file to write?

Comment: No, if you want to use printf, you should use `"%.2x"` or whatever - if you want to `std::fstream`, `std::cout` or similar, then you use `std::hex`, etc. I was more pointing out that "under the hood", formatted stream output still uses good old `printf`.

Comment: (obviously `fprintf` if you want to print to a file)